# DateTimeFormatterBuilder usages in Java 8, specifically optionals

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, jodatime

I'm trying to move from Joda to Java 8's `ZonedDateTime` and I'm hitting a wall with the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` that I cannot seem to work around.

I want to accept any of these formats:

```
2013-09-20T07:00:33
2013-09-20T07:00:33.123
2013-09-20T07:00:33.123+0000
2013-09-20T07:00:33.123Z
2013-09-20T07:00:33.123Z+0000
2013-09-20T07:00:33+0000
```

Here is my current builder:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
        .optionalStart()
        .appendPattern(".SSS")
        .optionalEnd()
        .optionalStart()
        .appendZoneId()
        .optionalEnd()
        .optionalStart()
        .appendPattern("Z")
        .optionalEnd()
        .toFormatter();
```

I'm probably wrong, but it appears that should match the patterns I want... right?

If anyone could point of what I may have missed, it'd be appreciated. I'm also not too sure of the use of `appendOffset`, so clarity on that is also appreciated if it turns out to be the answer.

**Edit:**

```
Text '2013-09-20T07:00:33.061+0000' could not be parsed at index 23
```

Looking at the builder, this appears to match due to the optional stages?

**Edit 2:**

After seeing advice from the first answer, I tried this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
        .optionalStart()
        .appendPattern(".SSS")
        .optionalEnd()
        .optionalStart()
        .appendZoneOrOffsetId()
        .optionalEnd()
        .toFormatter()
```

It continues to fail on the string above.

**Edit 3:**

Latest tests result in this exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2013-09-20T07:00:33.061+0000' could not be parsed at index 23
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1947)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1849)
at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:597)
at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:582)
```

Comment: "I'm probably wrong, but it appears that should match the patterns I want... right?" Did you try to match them in a test program? What happened?

Comment: @hexafraction yeah just put a few strings through; this one specifically is causing issue: `Text '2013-09-20T07:00:33.061+0000' could not be parsed at index 23`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It may be the reason that `+0000` is not a zone id, but a zone offset.

the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) offers this list:

```
  Symbol       Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
  ------       -------                     ------------      -------
       V       time-zone ID                zone-id           America/Los_Angeles; Z; -08:30
       z       time-zone name              zone-name         Pacific Standard Time; PST
       O       localized zone-offset       offset-O          GMT+8; GMT+08:00; UTC-08:00;
       X       zone-offset 'Z' for zero    offset-X          Z; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;
       x       zone-offset                 offset-x          +0000; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;
       Z       zone-offset                 offset-Z          +0000; -0800; -08:00;
```

You may use `appendOffset("+HHMM", "0000")` ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOffset-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)) or `appendZoneOrOffsetId()` ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendZoneOrOffsetId--))  instead of `appendZoneId()`.

so your full formatter may look like the following

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
                .optionalStart()
                .appendPattern(".SSS")
                .optionalEnd()
                .optionalStart()
                .appendZoneOrOffsetId()
                .optionalEnd()
                .optionalStart()
                .appendOffset("+HHMM", "0000")
                .optionalEnd()
                .toFormatter();
```

Further the way of creating a ZonedDateTime may influence if there is an exception or not. Therefore I'd recommend the following as this worked without any exceptions.

```
LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.parse("2013-09-20T07:00:33.123+0000", formatter);
ZonedDateTime zonedTime = time.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Comment: With or without the `appendPattern`? The string I left in the question is still erroring with `appendZoneOrOffsetId`

Comment: basically I'd say without, but I'm not sure about `2013-09-20T07:00:33.123Z+0000` because it has the cero-time Z and +0000 offset. As far as I know about this times Z and +0000 mean the same.

Comment: ok; I tried that and it fails on `2013-09-20T07:00:33.061+0000` - I added my modifications to the question, in case I misunderstood.

Comment: You may even use `appendOffset("+HHMM", "0000")` instead of `appendZoneOrOffsetId()`. I did minor testing and the latter seem to expect "+HH:MM" (with colon) formatted offsets.

Comment: I appreciate the testing. I copied what you had over, but `2013-09-20T07:00:33.061+0000` is still not working correctly... any ideas? Every form I can think of hasn't seemed to work.

Comment: is there an exception or is the result not correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75557/discussion-between-sailingthoms-and-zackehh).

Comment: I'm using your solution and it doesn't parse `2016-03-21T14:34:06.395000`. The `optionalStart()` doesn't really do anything. If I needed two formatters,    `.parseCaseInsensitive().append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME).optionalStart().appendOffset("+HHmm", "Z").toFormatter();` and                `.parseCaseInsensitive().append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME).toFormatter();` and basically try to parse twice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `.appendPattern("ZZZ")`? it would probably work!