# Convert Date ( Google Calendar api ) to Date with timezone

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a `localdatetime` to Date (which I use in Google Calendar api method)

```
Zone Id = "America/New_York"
```

I always, get this result :

```
2021-08-10T00:00:00.000+02:00
```

+02:00 is my local time zone

I want to get `-04:00 America/New_York` in same format as above

Here is the method

```
public static Date toDate(LocalDateTime startTime, String zoneId) {
    ZoneId zonedId = ZoneId.of(zoneId);
    return Date.from(Instant.from(startTime.atZone(zonedId)));
}
```

Please anyone can help?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. An old-fashioned `Date` hasn’t got, as in cannot have a format. Nor a time zone nor a UTC offset. So no, no one can help you give you one that has.

Comment: A [mre], please? Also asking because from `toDate(LocalDateTime.of(2021, Month.AUGUST, 10, 0, 0), "America/New_York")` I get `Tue Aug 10 06:00:00 CEST 2021`. It looks nothing like the `2021-08-10T00:00:00.000+02:00     
` that you reported getting.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**A sample solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:** You can use [`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-) for this purpose.

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId sourceZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");
        ZonedDateTime zdtSource = ZonedDateTime.now(sourceZone);
        System.out.println(zdtSource);

        ZoneId targetZone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
        ZonedDateTime zdtTarget = zdtSource.withZoneSameInstant(targetZone);
        System.out.println(zdtTarget);
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
2021-08-10T20:06:24.023038+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
2021-08-10T14:06:24.023038-04:00[America/New_York]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/WGivEr)

#### What if I need `OffsetDateTime`?

You can use [`ZonedDateTime#toOffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toOffsetDateTime--) to get `OffsetDateTime` out of a `ZonedDateTime` object e.g.

```
OffsetDateTime odtTarget = zdtTarget.toOffsetDateTime();
```

**Note:** For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `ZonedDateTime` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(zdtTarget.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for everyone , I read the comments and got the idea how to solve it from the comments then I ended up with the following code

```
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;

   public static DateTime toGoogleDateTime(LocalDateTime startTime, String zoneId) {
    ZonedDateTime zdtSource = startTime.atZone(ZoneId.of(zoneId));
    Date date = Date.from(zdtSource.toInstant());
    return new DateTime(date, TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of(zoneId)));
}
```

the zoneId gets from

https://gist.github.com/adamgen/3f2c30361296bbb45ada43d83c1ac4e5

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use a [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).
If that is not sufficient,
try [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html).

Take a look at [DateTimeFormatterBuilder usages in Java 8, specifically optionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710898/datetimeformatterbuilder-usages-in-java-8-specifically-optionals) for examples of using a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

To get `java.util.Date` from with proper Zone conversion, first use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` from `java.time` and finally use `SimpleDateFormat` to get `java.util.Date`.

```
public static Date toDate(LocalDateTime startTime, String zoneId) throws ParseException {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    ZonedDateTime source = startTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Dhaka"));
    ZonedDateTime result = source.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(zoneId));
    String date = result.format(formatter);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    return format.parse(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this and found an easy solution, so I thought I should share it.

I just used a `toString` method:

`date.toString()` and then modify the String.

```
 private static String getFormattedDate(DateTime date) {
        String string = date.toString();
        String result = StringUtils.substring(string, 0, string.length() - 5);
        return result;
    }
```