# DateTimeParseException while parsing date using ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, datetimeoffset, zoneddatetime

I have the below program and looks like ZonedDateTime is not able to parse the date string. Should I use a different date format or different library to parse?

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String inputDate = "2022-03-12T03:59:59+0000Z";
        ZonedDateTime.parse(inputDate, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME).toEpochSecond();
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-03-12T03:59:59+0000Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2053)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952)
    at java.base/java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:599)
    at Scratch.main(scratch_29.java:7)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Does the string always end in `+0000Z` literally? As has been said, it’s funny and non-standard. Could you educate the publisher to give you true [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format?

Comment: If you can’t change the string, I’d declare `private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME).appendOffset("+HHMM", "+0000").appendOffsetId().toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);` (sorry, unreadable in the comment, but simpler than the one by stdunbar). And I’d prefer to parse into an `OffsetDateTime` over`ZonedDateTime` (both work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't a ISO_DATE_TIME format.  That would require something like `2022-03-12T03:59:59+0000` (no 'Z').  A formatter that works looks something like:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;


class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String inputDate = "2022-03-12T03:59:59+0000Z";

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
                .optionalStart()
                .appendPattern(".SSS")
                .optionalEnd()
                .optionalStart()
                .appendZoneOrOffsetId()
                .optionalEnd()
                .optionalStart()
                .appendOffset("+HHMM", "0000")
                .optionalEnd()
                .optionalStart()
                .appendLiteral('Z')
                .optionalEnd()
                .toFormatter();

        long epochSecond = ZonedDateTime.parse(inputDate, formatter).toEpochSecond();

        System.out.println("epochSecond is " + epochSecond);
    }
}
```

as derived from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710898/datetimeformatterbuilder-usages-in-java-8-specifically-optionals).  You can create that formatter in one place and use it over again.

Comment: Will this work for ISO_DATE_TIME format as well?

Comment: yes. looks like it will work.

Comment: The optional part allows this.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Your input happens to be a screwy variation of the standard IS0 8601 format used by default with the `java.time.Instant` class. Fix your input string, and parse.

```
Instant.parse( "2022-03-12T03:59:59+0000Z".replace( "+0000Z" , "Z" ) )
```

Or, reformatted:

```
Instant.parse
( 
    "2022-03-12T03:59:59+0000Z"
    .replace( "+0000Z" , "Z" ) 
)
```

See this code run live at [IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/).

> 2022-03-12T03:59:59Z

But the very best solution is to use only ISO 8601 formats when exchanging date-time values.

## Details

### `ZonedDateTime` inappropriate here

`ZonedDateTime` is the wrong class for your input. Your input has a `Z` which is a standard abbreviation for an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. But no time zone indicated, only a mere offset. So use `OffsetDateTime` or `Instant` rather than `ZonedDateTime`.

### `+0000` and `Z` redundant

The `+0000` also means an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds. This is the same meaning as the `Z`. So this part is redundant. I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. No need to invent formats such as seen in your input.

### String manipulation rather than custom formatter

If all your inputs have the same ending of `+0000Z`, I suggest you clean the incoming data rather than define a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "2022-03-12T03:59:59+0000Z".replace( "+0000Z" , "Z" ) ;
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

### Other formats

You later [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71474684/datetimeparseexception-while-parsing-date-using-zoneddatetime/71475140?noredirect=1#comment126353249_71475140):

> "2017-01-04T12:30:00-05:00" , "2017-03-20T22:05:00Z", etc. So I cannot assume all my inputs to have the same ending of +0000Z.

Both of those are standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. Both can be parsed as [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) objects as-is, without alteration.

So I still maintain that the simplest approach, given your range of possible inputs, is to do the [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) string manipulation first, which has no effect if your other two formats arrive. Then parse all three variations as `OffsetDateTime` objects. Sometimes programmers tend to over-think a problem, and over-engineer an elaborate solution where a simple one suffices.

Example code:

```java
OffsetDateTime odt1 = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2022-03-12T03:59:59+0000Z".replace( "+0000Z" , "Z" ) ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt2 = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-01-04T12:30:00-05:00".replace( "+0000Z" , "Z" ) ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt3 = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-03-20T22:05:00Z".replace( "+0000Z" , "Z" ) ) ;
```

> 2022-03-12T03:59:59Z
>
> 2017-01-04T12:30-05:00
>
> 2017-03-20T22:05Z

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/oLFEBh).

Trap for `DateTimeParseException` while parsing to detect yet another unexpected format.

Of course, the best solution is to **educate the publisher of your data about consistent use of ISO 8601** formats such as the latter two examples, while avoiding the screwy first example’s format.

### Count since epoch

I recommend against tracking time as a count-since-epoch. Such a count is inherently ambiguous and error-prone. Instead, use text in standard ISO 8601 format. But if you insist on a count, here it is.

To get a count of seconds since the epoch reference of 1970-01-01T00:00Z, extract a `Instant` from the `OffsetDateTime`, and interrogate.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = odt.toInstant().getEpochSecond() ;
```

Comment: For my part I’d prefer the custom formatter (reusing `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` as part of it) over string manipulation. I upvoted for the good information about `ZonedDateTime` being inappropriate and redundancy.

Comment: Thank you Basil. My input can have different format as well. For example, "2017-01-04T12:30:00-05:00" , "2017-03-20T22:05:00Z", etc. So I cannot assume all my inputs to have the same ending of +0000Z. I cannot predict. So I think date formatter with several optional parts fits better for my usecase.

Comment: @Zack See my edits at bottom of Answer. Really no need to build an elaborate custom formatter for your three mentioned formats. Just do `String#replace` on all incoming strings. If there is nothing to replace, you get back the original string, no problem. I would rather read (and debug!) a single `replace` call than a 15-calls-long method chain. But, to each his own.

Comment: Yes. I understand . I like the replace approach too but then I have to do some testing and make sure it works fine for several incoming formats. Best approach would be to have an agreement with the publisher (long term solution). I will try out the replace approach and update if I find anything that does not work. Thanks again Basil.

Comment: Actually my requirement is to get epoch second from the input date string.  So I might just use Instant with replacement. String input = "2022-03-12T03:59:59+0000Z".replace( "+0000Z" , "Z" ) ;
long epochSeconds = Instant.parse( input ).getEpochSecond() ;

Comment: @Zack You can call OffsetDateTime toInstant getEpochSecond

Comment: Is `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[XXX][XX][X]")` that hard to read or debug? As you said, each must decide for themself. It parses all the mentioned examples fine. Again one may reuse `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` for the non-optional part if desired (I would).

Comment: @OleV.V. Any Java programmer can recognize the meaning `.replace( "+0000Z" , "Z" )`. Very few could decipher `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[XXX][XX][X]")`.  I am fairly comfortable with *java.time*, but even I would have to look up the meaning of single, double, and triple uppercase `X` and what they mean in succession in a formatter. I'm not saying the formatter-based solution is *wrong*; I am saying that *in this case* it is overkill with string manipulation being much simpler. In other more complicated cases, the formatter approach might well be more appropriate.